# Flutter: can’t determine the type of “Main.storyboard”. This may be due to a missing SDK

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

When i try run the flutter App on ios
return this error after running xcode success

```
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           691.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Interface Builder can’t determine the type of “Main.storyboard”. This may be due to a missing SDK.
/Users/mahdi/AndroidStudioProjects/famousFireStor/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard 
Error (Xcode): Interface Builder can’t determine the type of “LaunchScreen.storyboard”. This may be due to a missing SDK.
/Users/mahdi/AndroidStudioProjects/famousFireStor/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

Comment: and when try open any of these missing files 
such as Main.storyboard I can't open it and
return this error Interface Builder can’t determine the type of “Main.storyboard”. This may be due to a missing SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file and get new same file then  flutter clean and flutter pub get
now working